# I'm a god. I'm not the God

Tags: meaning, grammar

In ['Groundhog Day'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZUlq0lil1w) Bill Murray's character said "I'm a god. I'm not the God."

What does "I'm a god" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oxford Living Dictionaries has these definitions for the word ***god***:

> ***[God](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/god)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 1. (in Christianity and other monotheistic religions) the creator and ruler of the universe and source of all moral authority; the supreme being.
> 2. (in certain other religions) a superhuman being or spirit worshipped as having power over nature or human fortunes; a deity.
>
>    *‘a moon god’*
>    *‘the Hindu god Vishnu’*

*Groundhog Day* was set in the US where christianity dominates.  That is, a lot of Americans believe in the "*one true god*".  In the movie, Murray is saying that although he believes himself to be ***a*** god (definition #2), he is not ***the*** (christian) god (definition #1).

Comment: If I say "I'm ``a`` god" it doesn't means God, right?

Comment: Yes, the ***a*** indicates that you are one god among, possibly, many.  (Note that there is also another definition I didn't include: _A greatly admired or influential person._ which could also apply here.  I didn't include it as Murray's character clearly meant definition #2.)  Note that when writing about ***the*** god, the word "god" is generally capitalized.  (I'm an atheist so I don't bother, but that's just me.)

Comment: I'm atheist too))

Comment: Also remember Groundhog Day was Ramis and Murray, and [when someone asks you if you're a god you say yes](https://youtu.be/I6LD6ITN2dk)

Answer (score 0):

He is clearly referring to supernatural powers that he has somehow obtained, making him way higher over mere humans.

However, he qualifies himself, and warns that he is not G-d as the audience knows him. Not the one that people pray to, or that is responsible for creating the universe. Rather, he just has superhuman capabilities and powers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ah a typo see edits please